# uinavigation controller delegate not work with MFSideMenu

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app with an "old" Tabbarcontroller and a MainWindow.xib. I have to delete the tabbarcontroller logic to transform the app and made a "Left side menu" type, like facebook. I have a problem, i have alredy created the left side menù with a tableviewcontroller and i can open,close and push correctly my controllers... Now i want to insert a different customnavigation bar class each navigation controller (in the old version of the app each navigation controller had his custom navigation class to change che image in relation with the active viewcontroller). This is the code i use in the tableview didselect method of a row in my left side menu:

```
 if (indexPath.row==1) {

    DemoViewController *demoController = [[DemoViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = self.menuContainerViewController.centerViewController;
    [navigationController setValue:[[CustomNavigationBar alloc]init] forKeyPath:@"navigationBar"];
    NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:demoController];
    navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
    [self.menuContainerViewController setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed];
}
```

this code manage correctly the slide and load correctly the viewcontroller inside MFSideMenu. The custom navigationbar class is assigned but not works correctly:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{
```

this method is never called, maybe MFSideMenu overwrites the uinavigationcontroller delegate? How i can do to made "active" again this navigation controller delegate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution,this code:

```
      DemoViewController *demoController = [[DemoViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = self.menuContainerViewController.centerViewController;

    CustomNavigationBar *navClass=[[CustomNavigationBar alloc]init];
    [navigationController setValue:navClass forKeyPath:@"navigationBar"];
    [navigationController setDelegate:navClass];

    NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:demoController];
    navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
    [self.menuContainerViewController setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed];
```

instead of:

```
DemoViewController *demoController = [[DemoViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = self.menuContainerViewController.centerViewController;
[navigationController setValue:[[CustomNavigationBar alloc]init] forKeyPath:@"navigationBar"];
NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:demoController];
navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
[self.menuContainerViewController setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed];
```

In this way the delegate is assigned correctly...